# git whatchanged - what does -M do?

Tags: git, repository, git-log

I am looking at some code that uses the -M (capital M, not lowercase, which is documented as include merges) flag passed to Git whatchanged.

I can't see a definition for the flag in the man page (for 1.8.3.1).  Can anyone advise what it does?  Is it the opposite of -m (lowercase)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The doc is the git log. git whatchanged is deprecated. use git log instead.

> -M
>   --find-renames[=]
>
> If generating diffs, detect and report renames for each commit.
>
> For following files across renames while traversing history, see --follow.
>
> If n is specified, it is a threshold on the similarity index (i.e. amount of addition/deletions compared to the file’s size). For example, -M90% means Git should consider a delete/add pair to be a rename if more than 90% of the file hasn’t changed. Without a % sign, the number is to be read as a fraction, with a decimal point before it. I.e., -M5 becomes 0.5, and is thus the same as -M50%. Similarly, -M05 is the same as -M5%. To limit detection to exact renames, use -M100%.
>
> The default similarity index is 50%.